# Best format for registration form?

Tags: usability, forms, user-expectation, layout, login

I am working on a registration form. I am trying to find the friendliest way to organize the content. I would appreciate if you could tell me:
1. Which layout you find better
2. If double checking the password is essential
3. Any comments or suggestions are welcomed and appreciated too :)

[image: a. content aligned to the left b. content on the same row]

[image: c. content in two rows]

Comment: Images are broken for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I liked A better. Reason because it is easier to scan (top to bottom) than top to bottom and left to right on B . Also, you can adjust the width of the text fields to give variety. Like for example,  the width of the the password section a little shorter than the rest and the address bar bigger as it will load more info than the rest. Another suggestion is if you can minimize the number of fields to be answered, so that users won't feel too overwhelmed. The faster they can register the better. You can also add a button "connect to facebook or twitter" so you can speed the registration more. I suggest giving examples on placeholders instead of repeating the title of the field for more clarity. Cancel buttons should be not too prominent if you like to attract more successful registrations.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest b, as it goes straight from top to bottom and has labels to the left, which in my opinion are easier to read in this case, and make the whole form more compact.

I would remove the need to repeat password - it will not protect User from forgetting the pass, and passwords are entered quite carefully, so typos are rare. Should it happen though, they will be able to use a password reset link.

Should they be not crucial for registration I would also try to remove some fields that are not crucial.

Answer (score 0):

It is depend on the requirement. If this is going to be a responsive layout,it is good to have option b. for desktop and option a. for smaller device screens. As per my opinion, in an smaller devices, option b. will not give you a better layout with long text label and the long text box width.